# My game controller's charging port broke. Now I'm trying to make it run on replaceable batteries, but I'm having some problems

Tags: batteries, voltage-divider

The controller needs 3.7 volts and 250 mAh. I have Kirkland Signature AA batteries. Each are 1.5 volts. Not sure the mAh or whatever that is. How could I raise the voltage from 3 (2 AA batteries) to 3.7, or lower from 4.5 (3 AA batteries) to 3.7? How can I get the mAh right? Is there some other super simple option I'm missing. I could probably buy another charging port or something, but the pins are so small so that would be too hard to connect.

Edit: Found a solution to the voltage problem I believe. Making a voltage divider with one resistor being 8 ohms, and the other being 37 ohms. Still got the mAh thing though.

Comment: No, a voltage divider should only be used to provide a reference voltage for technical reasons in circuit designs - it should almost *never* be used as a source of power to electronic devices, it will drain your battery quickly, not to say the voltage is unregulated and may vary wildly depending on the load. To raise or drop voltage correctly and efficiently, you should get a buck-boost converter board. Finally, mAh is only a measurement of battery capacity, it's not something to worry about.

Comment: A (simpler) alternative to a buck and/or boost converter is to run your batteries at 4.5V and use a low dropout regulator. This should be fine for low-current loads.

Comment: @比尔盖子 Oh, I didn't know that about mAh. So if I wanna do this, I need a buck-boost converter board? So what would be the cheapest option to repair this? Should I get rechargeable AA batteries that are 1.2 volts? 3 of them would be 3.6, which is super close to 3.7. It's not like batteries stay at the voltage they say they are anyway, so I think that would work? I could put the rechargeable batteries outside, then when I wanna charge it I could pop out the batteries or something?

Comment: @StarCat I looked it up on amazon. Is it the little 4 pin things? How would I connect them? And how would I know which to use?

Comment: You could use a diode in series with three batteries ro get 4.5V-0.7V=3.8V

Comment: 3 rechargeable NIMH batteries would provide 3.6v (1.2v each) most of the time. Fresh charged, they would put out 3.9 or 4, but so would the "3.7v" li-ion it came with, so no big whoop.

Comment: @SimSon Just a diode?

Comment: @dandavis K, thanks. I'll think about that.

Comment: @EmeraldVolts yes, a silicon diode drops about 0.7V, more or less independent of the current. Though it just dissipates power, how much depends on the amount of current passing through (which you didn't tell)